# Why my modal spinner disapears before the end of process on R shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, dashboard, shinydashboard

I'm working on an R Shiny dashboard. When I click the run button, the dashboard processes the data and creates two tabs ('tab1' and 'tab2'). This step takes 10-15 seconds, depending on the size of the loaded data. I have added a modal spinner using the shinybusy library in R.

However, I have encountered a problem with this modal spinner. The spinner disappears after the creation of tab1, but I would like it to continue until the creation of tab2, until the process is complete.

```
observeEvent(input$run, {
  show_modal_spinner(text="Preaparing plots...", session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())
    insertTab(
      inputId = 'a_tabs',
      tabPanel("tab1",
               fluidRow(
                 column(
                   width=8,
                   #plotOutput(...)
                 )
               )
      )
    )
    insertTab(
      inputId = 'a_tabs',
      tabPanel("tab2",
               fluidRow(
                 column(
                   width=8,
                   #plotOutput(...)
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  remove_modal_spinner()
})
```

What am I doing wrong with the modal spinner ? Is there others solutions ?

Comment: can you wrap the remove modal part into an if condition e.g. when all data is loaded?